# How extract information into array from given Text?

Tags: php, arrays, extract

Consider a text of the form

```
@article{refregier2003weak,   
title={Weak gravitational lensing by large-scale structure},   
author={Refregier, Alexandre},  
journal={Annual Review of Astronomy and Astrophysics},  
volume={41}, 
pages={645},   
year={2003},   
publisher={Annual Reviews, Inc.} 
}
```

where "refregier2003weak" is the ID of the article. The order of the labels, title, author , journal ... may change from one article to the other and in some case some labels may be missing in some articles.

How to extract the values of these labels and the ID of the article in an array using PHP?

Comment: *Ah!*, how? I guess you need to write some PHP code. (=> Show us your attempt and we will help you to get it to work)

Comment: I only have good knowledge in Javascript. My knowledge about PHP however is limited. I don't really know where to start.

Comment: If you understand JavaScript, you could solve it and simply translate to the equivalent methods. `text.split('\n').forEach(function (line) { var split = line.split('{'); var key = line.shift(), val = line.join('{'); switch (key) { ... } });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick solution:

```
<?php

$input = '@article{refregier2003weak,   
title={Weak gravitational lensing by large-scale structure},   
author={Refregier, Alexandre},  
journal={Annual Review of Astronomy and Astrophysics},  
volume={41}, 
pages={645},   
year={2003},   
publisher={Annual Reviews, Inc.} 
}';
$pattern = '@(\w+)=\{(.*)\}@';
$articleIdPattern = '|@article\{(.*?),|';
preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $matches);
preg_match_all($articleIdPattern, $input, $articleMatches);

$result = [];
if (isset($matches[1]) && isset($matches[2])) {
    foreach ($matches[1] as $key => $value) {
        if (isset ($matches[2][$key])) {
            $result[$value] = $matches[2][$key];
        }
    }
}
if (isset($articleMatches[1][0])) {
    $result['article'] = $articleMatches[1][0];
}

var_dump($result);
```

http://ideone.com/K0WPVg

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with simple substring methods. For example:

```
$parsed = array();
foreach (explode("\n", $text) as $line) { // Split by line
    list ($key, $value) = explode('{', $line, 2); // Split by the first { ($key is text to the left, $val is text to the right)
    $value = substr($value, 0, strrpos($value, '}')); // Strip off everything after the last }
    switch ($key) {
        case '@article': $parsed['articleId'] = $value; break;
        case 'title={': $parsed['title'] = $value; break;
        case 'author={': // ...
    }
}

var_dump($parsed);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work as long as you only intend on parsing one at a time.

Remember to change the name of $inputString for your input string

```
<?php  
preg_match_all('/@article\{(.*?),/', $inputString, $id);
preg_match_all('/(.+)={(.*?)}/', $inputString, $meta);
$arrayResults = array("id" => $id[1][0]);
foreach($meta[1] as $key => $someMeta){
    $arrayResults[$someMeta] = $meta[2][$key];
}
var_dump($arrayResults);
?>
```

Produces this:

```
Array
(
    [id] => refregier2003weak
    [title] => Weak gravitational lensing by large-scale structure
    [author] => Refregier, Alexandre
    [journal] => Annual Review of Astronomy and Astrophysics
    [volume] => 41
    [pages] => 645
    [year] => 2003
    [publisher] => Annual Reviews, Inc.
)
```